# SQL missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql

I have no nerves left.

Here is the code :

```
select o.embg from objekti o
   where o.embg not in (
      select s.embg, t.time
      from objekti o, sopstvenici s, tipovi t
      where o.embg = s.embg and o.tid = t.tid and t.time = 'Куќа'
      order by o.embg
   )
```

Results in an error:

> 0RA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot put `ORDER BY` inside the parenthesis.  Move it up to the end of the previous line after the second `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Also, the "not in" statement could not be used with a "select" statement that return multiple fields right ?

Comment: Also true. I missed the t.time in the sub-query.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't return two columns in that sub-select (because you want to compare it with the `embg` field). Also, you don't care about the order of the sub-select. Try something like this instead,

```
select o.embg from objekti o where o.embg not in (select s.embg from
  sopstvenici s,tipovi t where o.embg=s.embg and 
  o.tid=t.tid and t.time='Куќа') 
order by o.embg
```